# How to see Diffie Hellman private key used during negotiation?

Tags: diffie-hellman, openssl

I used OpenSSL `s_client` to connect to a test server.

Because OpenSSL generated client side private DH key, I think there will be a way to show the private key or enforce a specific private key to be used in negotiation for test purposes.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the command line use of a cryptographic tool. Please ask on superuser instead.

Comment: No, libssl won't show, or set, the ephemeral private key -- unless you intervene manually with a debugger, or change the source and rebuild which you can because it's open source. `s_client` does show the (derived) _master secret_ for the session, which is sufficient to decrypt eavesdropped traffic; there are multiple Qs about that on security.SX and perhaps some other Stacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you happen to know a tool that does show it? Debugging or rebuild is too complex for me.